# how to merge elasticsearch results into one field or how to explain which field results were found in

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

follow me on this one...

if i've got a db of movies and i want to search on multiple fields and return the results into a single field, how would i accomplish this?

let me set an example...

my documents have a title and artists.name (array). i want the user to be able to search in both title and artist at the same time so that the results are in the same field. this would be implemented in an 'autocomplete' search scenario where you get results as you type.

so if a user types 'mike' i want to be able to search for actors (artists.name) with the name mike and titles with the word mike in it. in this case, you might return 'magic mike' and 'mike meyers' in the same autocomplete result set. (imdb.com has this implementation)

i understand how to search both of those fields, but how do i return them into one? i believe i'd have to have some knowledge on where my 'hit' came from - title or artists.name. so maybe that's the larger question here - how do i tell which field the hit came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any direct ways to determine which field(s) a query matched on.  I can think of a few "workaround" approaches that may do it for you- one is by using the [multisearch api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search), and executing separate queries on each field.  Another is using [highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#search-request-highlighting), which will return back the fields that a match was found in.

**Example using multi search:**

```cs
var response = client.MultiSearch(ms => ms
    .Search<Artist>("name", s => s.Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(a => a.Name).Query("mike"))))
    .Search<Artist>("titles", s => s.Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(a => a.Titles).Query("mike")))));

response.GetResponse<Artist>("name"); // <-- Contains search results from matching on Name
response.GetResponse<Artist>("titles"); // <-- Contains search results from matching on Titles
```

**Example using highlighting:**

```cs
var response = client.Search<Artist>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(m => m
            .OnFields(a => a.Name, a => a.Titles)
            .Query("mike")))
    .Highlight(h => h
        .OnFields(fs => fs.OnField(a => a.Name),
                  fs => fs.OnField(a => a.Titles))));
```

You can then inspect the Highlights object of each hit, or the Highlights object of the response to determine what field the match came from.

There is also the [explain api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html#search-explain), and you can add [explain](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) to your query, but that will return a lot of irrelevant scoring info, which you would have to parse through.  Probably too cumbersome for your needs.

As a side note- for autocomplete functionality, if possible I would really try to leverage the [completion suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#search-suggesters-completion) instead of the above solutions.  These are pre-computed suggestions that are created when you index your documents by building up [FSTs](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/12/using-finite-state-transducers-in.html), which will increase your indexing time as well as index size, but as a result will provide extremely fast suggestions.

Comment: thanks greg. very helpful as usual. i began to think along those lines as well - but mine were more archaic... i was going to execute a separate query for each and just merge the results somehow. i will look into using the suggester - my phrase queries were fast - 25ms or less, but if that's even faster then that would be great.

Comment: also - per your comment - i don't think i would use the completion suggester INSTEAD of the above suggestions would i? if i were to use it, i'd still need to use a similar technique to search multiple locations, and then push them together, correct?

Comment: also - i just downloaded the latest elasticsearch 1.2.1 since it now has the [Context Suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) feature which might fit my case.  Unfortunately, i can't get it to work - following their example on that page. i get the following:      "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[services][2] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: NullPointerException; "

Comment: Actually, I would recommend using the completion suggester as an alternative.  It would probably require you to rethink and restructure your index and application, but it is probably worth looking into if you want a fast auto-complete.  Then again, the above may suffice- up to you to decide what's best for your application.  I'm actually not familiar with the context suggester yet, it's fairly new and I haven't used it, so unfortunately I can't offer much help there.